# Contraction of a tensor by vector

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have an expression: $g(X,Y)+s(Y) =0$, and I want to contract it by Y, that is to write it as $X+?$, what can I do with s(Y)? Here, g is a metric and s is a (1,0) tensor.

Comment: Are you sure you should be adding tensors of different types? Tensor contraction and many other operations tend to be meaningless for such expressions.

Comment: I have another expression multiplying s(Y), but doesn't contain Y... I just need to contract s(Y).

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. As I've said, expressions adding tensors of different types are generically meaningless, and it typically means you've made a mistake. I also don't know what you mean by "contract $s(Y)$". The expression $s(Y)$ is _already_ contracted, it is $s$ contracted with $Y$.

Comment: How can I write s(Y) without Y? Same for g(X,Y), we can write it as X. I need an expression without Y. Maybe contraction is not a good term? Sorry for not explaining well.

Comment: One way would be to use [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation). You would write $s$ as $s_i$ and $g$ as $g_{ij}$. You would then write $X^i$ and $Y^i$ respectively. Contraction would be repeated indices up and down. I suspect what you want is something like this $g_{ij}X^i + s_j$, in which $g$ has been contracted with $X$. In index-free notation, the closest might be something like $g(X,\_) + s(\_)$.

Comment: Is there something similar as $g(grad\alpha, X)=X\alpha$? I do not need $g$ in the expression, so that if I take an inner product of the contracted expression by Y, I get g(X, Y) + s(Y)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are you trying to _invert_ for $X$? In that case you need to use the inverse metric.

Comment: Yes, like from X we get g(X,Y), I want to get s(Y) frm some expression. Do you know where can I find an explanation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40577/discussion-between-euyu-and-novak-djokovic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your equation is true for *every* vector $Y$, then you can write it as $X^\flat + s = 0$ or alternatively $X + s^\sharp = 0$. Here $s^\sharp$ is the vector corresponding to the one-form $s$ through raising an index - see [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).